# Spring pageable parameter not set on @query

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

The following [Pageable Query](https://pastebin.com/1xcu3ubL) takes a PageRequest Class as second parameter. It seems to be the cause of the Exception.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#2" is not set; SQL statement: ... order by message0_.id desc limit ? [90012-187]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.expression.Parameter.checkSet(Parameter.java:80)
    at org.h2.command.Prepared.checkParameters(Prepared.java:164)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:89)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:197)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 98 more
```

UPDATE: Tried removing the second parameter just to see if it works but it's the same error it except it now point to "#1" instead of "#2" [See here](https://pastebin.com/cZcendj0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed parameter to take Ids instead of Symbol Class, which works.

```
@Query(value="select msg from Message msg left join msg.tickers ticker where ticker.symbol.id IN (:ids)")
Page<Tweet> findBySymbolIdsIn(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: This did the trick for me, I also could neither use an JPA Entity nor an enum, it had to be Long

Answer (score 0):

Try using **List**<> instead of **Set**<>. Change it to . Also change the method name to findBySymbolsIn()

```
@Query(value="select msg from Message msg left join msg.tickers ticker where ticker.symbol IN (:symbols)")
Page<Tweet> findBySymbolsIn(@Param("symbols") List<Symbol> symbols, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Can you try changing the method name to ***findBySymbolsIn()*** if that works .

Comment: Can you please share your entity models . Will check .

Comment: Did u tried executing the query you are seeing in logs . Does that works ? Can you try removing CASE part from you entity model and try once ?

Comment: Did you figure out the problem and fix for you problem? do share , curious to know what is causing this problem ..